# Zend framework 3 - DOMPDF

Tags: php, zend-framework, dompdf, zend-framework3

I'm trying to use DOMPDF module with ZF 3.

I've installed it with composer `composer require dino/dompdf-module` and looks ok.

[image: Installation via composer]

Then i've imported the dompdf module to my order controller

```
use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;
```

After that, i've created a new action called printOrderPdfAction() and a new view, here's the following code:

Controller:

```
public function printOrderPdfAction()
{
    $this->layout(FALSE);

    $pdf = new PdfModel();
    $pdf->setOption('filename', 'order-pdf');
    $pdf->setOption('paperSize', 'a4');
    $pdf->setOption('paperOrientation', 'portrait');

    $pdf->setVariables([
        'message' => 'This is a test message'
    ]);

    return $pdf;
}
```

View:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2><?= $this->message?></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

This should download automatically the pdf, however it's returning the view and it's not downloading the pdf file.

Like this:[image]

Anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: What happens when you delete `print-order-pdf.phtml`?

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing an issue where some browsers need quotes around the file name in the Content-Disposition header, otherwise the browser ignores the header and the file is not downloaded.

Example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.pdf
```

Should really be:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.pdf"
```

In DompdfModule the quotes were in fact missing. This has since been fixed in https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule/pull/67 and is slated to be released in `v0.5.0`.

You can try `dev-master` or the specific commit `7f11506a22ebabb3aac5e800eada1d8e85e22916` to see if this solves the problem you're experiencing.